# PyQGIS standalone script does not work. Error "QGraphicsScene::addItem: item has already been added to this scene"

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I try to test a PyQGIS standalone script which should just show one Shapefile.
Sounds pretty simple but does not work.

Here is my script:

```
from PyQt4 import *
from PyQt4 import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
import sys
import os

qgishome = "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis"

app = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgishome, True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.yellow)
canvas.enableAntiAliasing(True)
canvas.show()

layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"C:/daten/polygons.shp", "Testdaten", "ogr")
reg = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
reg.addMapLayer(layer)
canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])
QgsApplication.exitQgis()

app.exec_()

app.exitQgis()
```

The Window openes, I can see the yellow background but the Layer is not shown. instad of that there is an error message:

```
QGraphicsScene::addItem: item has already been added to this scene
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::repaintRequested() to QgsMapCanvas::ref
resh()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::layerCrsChanged() to QgsMapCanvas::laye
rCrsChange()
```

Sometimes this also brings python to crash, so that a windows error reporting is opened.

I loaded the neccessary environmental variables, which should be ok, as I can import qgis.core and qgis.gui without problems.

does anyone has an idea what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track.

The thing that bit you are the backslashes in your prefix path `\` which are escape sequences in python.
Just do it the same way as you do it with the layer path and use slashes `/` instead.

```
qgishome = "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis"
```

A useful snippet that you can run after `QgsApplication.initQgis()` that makes sure that the providers are loaded correctly is the following one, found [here](http://snorf.net/blog/2014/01/04/writing-unit-tests-for-qgis-python-plugins/).

```
if len(QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()) == 0:
    raise RuntimeError('No data providers available.')
```

or check `layer.isValid()` to see if the layer was really loaded correctly.

Another thing that you probably don't want to do is to call `QgsApplication.exitQgis()` before `app.exec_()`

And finally concerning the warnings, they are unrelated to your code and don't hurt at all. And I think they should be gone with the most recent release.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works great. Unfortunally there happened something weired to my useraccount here. My question isn't assignet to my account anymore, so I cannot mark it as answered or upvote the answer ;(